# Получение URL после редиректа

Tags: python-3.6

Нужно автоматизировать получение токена, есть ссылка которую отправляю, и получаю новую, в которой содержится токен. Как это сделать на питоне?

```
 r = requests.get(link)
print(r)
print(r.url)
```

в интернете нашел такой и похожие способы, но они возвращают ссылку до редиректа.

Comment: вы уверены что слово "редирект" в вашем случае подходит? Если да, то покажите что вы хотите получить на примере http://httpbin.org/#/Redirects

Comment: смысл в том, что в ручную я вставляю url  в адресную строку браузера, после чего получаю новую url, а мне нужно сделать это программно, прошу прощения, за недостаточное владение терминологией.

Comment: конкретный пример ввода вывода приведите. Допустим начальный url у вас http://httpbin.org/absolute-redirect/3 Какую из нескольких промежуточных ссылок вы хотели бы получить? Только последнюю?